# No se reflejan los cambios

Tags: javascript, html, css, cache

Tengo un problema extraño desde hace unos días vengo guardando los cambios en un servidor de Hostinger, tanto CSS como Javascript al principio cuando no se reflejaban los cambios en lugar de eliminar el caché del navegador lo que hacía yo era ingresar directamente a la dirección del fichero (Ejemplo: `miweb.com/css/estilo.css`) y dentro del fichero actualizaba con F5 ahora me pasa algo super extraño, no solamente no se me ve reflejado los cambios sino que cuando ingreso directamente a la dirección y actualizo sigue sin mostrar lo que he cambiado, aún cuando ingreso directamente desde el administrador de archivos del propio servidor y cuando voy a editar el archivo SI se muestra la linea que he cambiado.

Ya he probado a eliminar el caché y probé en navegadores diferentes

Comment: He intentado desde navegadores diferentes, en pc distintas, desde incógnito y es como si nunca hubiera editado nada

Comment: existe algo llamado "caching" que hacen los navegadores, y lo que hacen es básicamente es guardar en el cache los archivos y si se pide nuevamente la misma página web revisa si hay algún archivo nuevo o tiene que actualizar uno, ahora para actualizar un archivo no revisa si el contenido es diferente porque eso implicaría descargarlo siempre, hace otras comparaciones como el nombre o el tamaño del archivo así que si no cambiaste el nombre o el tamaño sigue siendo el mismo o al menos parecido simplemente no te actualizara el archivo, presiona Ctrl + F5

Comment: si al presionar Ctrl + F5 te actualiza el archivo es porque tienes que manejar versiones de los archivos para asegurar que cada vez que haces una actualización esta se descargue siempre, como por ejemplo `styles.1.css` y cuando actualices le cambias el nombre a `styles.1.1.css` por decirte algo, hay varias formas de manejar las versiones de tus archivos busca la adecuada para ti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando sucede esto, es posible que sea por cuestiones de manejo de caché del lado del servidor. Es decir, es el servidor quien tiene cargado ese archivo en memoria para reducir el tiempo de procesamiento que tarda en leer el archivo del disco. Esto es lo que hacen, por ejemplo las redes de distribución de contenido (CDN por sus siglas en inglés). Debés revisar la configuración del servidor y las políticas de caché de archivos, para que limpie la memoria y vuelva a leer el archivo del disco.

Comment: Dijiste la palabra que me resolvió el problema, precisamente estoy usando cloudflare y ya  lo configuré como modo desarrollo. Ahora si guarda mis cambios. Muchas gracias (y)

Comment: como configuraste eso en cloudflare  a mi me pasa eso y no he dado con la solucion

Answer (score 1):

La explicación de Niche es correcta a mi me paso:

> Cuando sucede esto, es posible que sea por cuestiones de manejo de
>   caché del lado del servidor. Es decir, es el servidor quien tiene
>   cargado ese archivo en memoria para reducir el tiempo de procesamiento
>   que tarda en leer el archivo del disco. Esto es lo que hacen, por
>   ejemplo las redes de distribución de contenido (CDN por sus siglas en
>   inglés). Debés revisar la configuración del servidor y las políticas
>   de caché de archivos, para que limpie la memoria y vuelva a leer el
>   archivo del disco.

en mi caso no tengo acceso a cambiar las configuraciones del servidor y cambio constantemente los script.

Si usas php agrega esto a tu pagina para cada script, así te aseguras que el servidor recargue el archivo e ignora todo lo que esta después de **?**
cundo llames a tu archivo solo incluye el nombre normal "miscript.js".

```
   int v = Random.Next();
   echo "<script src='miscript.js?'" + v + "></script>";
```

Un saludo.